# How can I fix a shaky touchpad cursor in Ubuntu on my hp pavilion laptop?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, cursor

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop and it works great, except after the initial reboot my touchpad cursor shakes violently when I hold my finger completely still on the pad.It works fine with a regular mouse plugged in. I couldn't find much scouting around the internet except that it might be that my touchpad doesn't have any dead zones? I am very new to Ubuntu and am fairly computer savvy, but I don't know a lot about using the terminal or anything like that, so if you could dumb down a fix for this as much as possible for me, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try tweaking your touchpad settings with the synclient command from the terminal.

The man page for synclient mentions the "pressure" value which tweaks capacitance on most modern touchpads.  It sounds particularly interesting in your scenario.

Comment: Ok. I put in the synclient command and i got back the response "couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?" I have synaptic package manager installed. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must configure synclient. In one single:

synclient VertHysteresis=40; synclient HorizHysteresis=40